# Error compiling Gradle from Android application: The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.3

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.7alpha-sa3cvc6"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.1.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the error from the "console" :

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
```

I don't know why, I had updated my Android Studio (from 2.2 to 2.3), also I had installed all the needed packages, all the necessary package (SDK and other). Before I upgraded my Android Studio, the configuration worked fine.

Comment: why don't you update buildtoolversion to 25.0.0?

Comment: better to latest `25.0.2`

Comment: I don't want update the build tools, bcause I get error with style components and other components

The error are those:http://i68.tinypic.com/67rrx3.png

Comment: build tools have nothing to styling. compileSdkVersion might have.

Comment: OK, well I tryed to set the lastest version of Gradle and buildTools, but I get some issues on 
    app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml


    Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.3) is too low for project

Update the `buildToolsVersion 25.0.2` but your real issue is here:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
```

Since you are using the **support libraries v24**, you **have to compile** with API 24+.

Also, **it is strongly recommended** that you always compile **with the latest SDK**.

Comment: Ok, I changed the compileSdkVersion and It works fine.
Grazie

Comment: @SimoneDalMas Mark the answer if it solves your issue. It can be useful for other users.